# Program throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using Bucket Sort on an array that's sorted backwards

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to run an array that's sorted backwards (I.E. 100, 99, 98, 97 . . . . 3, 2, 1, 0, highest to lowest) through a bucket sort that will sort it lowest to highest. The code that generates the array looks like this:

```
int n = 100;//Decides how large the arrays fed to the sorts are, minimum value of 100
int k = n - 1;
int howMany = 10;//Decides how many times the sorts are timed whenever the program is run
int[] baseArray = new int[n];

        //Loops entire thing as many times as howMany dictates, will refer to it as PRIME LOOP
        for (int m = 0; m < howMany; m++) { 

                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) //Generates array that's sorted backwards
                    {
                          baseArray[i] = k;
                          k--;
                    }

            int[] bucketArray = new int[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                bucketArray[i] = baseArray[i];
            }

            bucketSort(bucketArray); //Sends the array to bucket sort (This is line 218)**************
        }
```

Here's the actual bucket sort:

```
    //Bucket Sort
    public static void bucketSort(int[] input) {
        // get hash codes
        final int[] code = hash(input);
        
        // create and initialize buckets to ArrayList: O(n)
        List<Integer>[] buckets = new List[code[1]];
        for (int i = 0; i < code[1]; i++) {
          buckets[i] = new ArrayList();
        }
        
        // distribute data into buckets: O(n)
        for (int i : input) {
          buckets[hash(i, code)].add(i); //This is line 349*******************************************
        }
        
        // sort each bucket O(n)
        for (List bucket : buckets) {
          Collections.sort(bucket);
        }
        
        int ndx = 0;
        // merge the buckets: O(n)
        for (int b = 0; b < buckets.length; b++) {
          for (int v : buckets[b]) {
            input[ndx++] = v;
          }
        }
      }

      private static int[] hash(int[] input) {
        int m = input[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
          if (m < input[i]) {
            m = input[i];
          }
        }
        return new int[] { m, (int) Math.sqrt(input.length) };
      }

      private static int hash(int i, int[] code) {
        return (int) ((double) i / code[0] * (code[1] - 1));
      }
```

The first time the code goes through the for-loop (prime loop) bucket sort spits out the array with it properly sorted lowest to highest. However, without fail the second time it goes through the prime loop it gives me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, specifically,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 18 out of bounds for length 10
    at SeniorResearch.Final_Project_Driver.bucketSort(Final_Project_Driver.java:349)
    at SeniorResearch.Final_Project_Driver.main(Final_Project_Driver.java:218)
```

(I marked out the mentioned lines above)

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening? What's changing from PRIME LOOP 1 to PRIME LOOP 2 that's causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the bucket sort and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your bucketSort method at you think you are using  `final int[] code = hash(input);` to calculate the number of buckets, but in reality, you are calculating the hash of your array.

So what you have to do is calculate the number of **different** hash codes for your array elements.

Use the method which calculates the hash of a single integer, then count how many different hashes you've got, then add each integer into the "hash-bucket", and so on...

Comment: Can you explain why this isn't a problem in the first prime loop? Or why that if I give it an array that isn't sorted backwards (for example a randomized array) I don't have this problem?